# haml syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I got this error after compiling the following code

```
Exception on line 2: undefined method `render' for #<Object:0x10de902b0>
Use --trace for backtrace.
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

the code

```
%h1 New place
= render 'form'
= link_to 'Back', places_path
```

how can I fix this I always get this even with one more example

```
%p#notice= notice
  %p
    %b Title:
    = @place.title
```

and this is the exception!

```
Exception on line 1: undefined local variable or method `notice' for #<Object:0x108629270>
Use --trace for backtrace.
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

**update:
 It turns out that Codekit has some issue with Rails embedded code. so I decided to quit using it for now .**

Comment: How are you compiling your haml?

Comment: I am using codekit application http://incident57.com/codekit/

Comment: I'm not sure how this codekit works as I've never used it, but `render` and `link_to` are parts of *Ruby on Rails*, they're not built in to Haml. If you're trying to use Haml outside of Rails, you probably can't use those methods. Whatever object context your Haml code is executing in doesn't have those methods.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is I downloaded an open source application (rails application) and they used the same syntax. Codekit generated the same error. In my app and the open source one both are working generating syntax error!

Comment: If you're using Haml in the context of a Rails 3.1+ app, you don't have to compile it. The asset pipeline will compile it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sure there it a way to fix this. I am reading the HAML full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the space after the '='? That may solve it.

Comment: I solved the issue by not using CodeKit thanks for your answers.